# Auto linebreak in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text like

```
hello everyone. My name is PETER. hahahah ahahah ....
```

how can I auto linebreak this text if I have a width fixed make the text become like this:

```
hello everyone.
My name is
PETER. hahahah
ahahah
```

Comment: Where you want to line break it ? inside a `<div>` block ?

Comment: Any code in a [mcve] or at least a line or 2.

Comment: I make a textarea for canvas but it only get '\n' for linebreak 
but you know everyone alway use copy paste the text so I need to to make it auto linebeak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would you use a function like:

```js
const string = "hello everyone. My name is PETER. hahahah ahahah ...."

function autoLineBreaker(string, maxLength = 7) {
    const tableString = string.split(' ')
    let result = ""
    let intermediaryLength = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < tableString.length; i++) {
        const currentWord = tableString[i]
        if (intermediaryLength + currentWord.length > maxLength) {
            result += ` ${currentWord} \n`
            intermediaryLength = 0
        } else {
            result += ` ${currentWord}`
            intermediaryLength += currentWord.length
        }
    }
    return result
}

console.log(autoLineBreaker(string))
```

If you're also keen on ES8 syntax and functional programming, here is a factory for this function that you can use to avoid passing the length. The syntax is a bit more evolved version :

```js
const string = "hello everyone. My name is PETER. hahahah ahahah ...."
const makeAutoLinebreakerES8 = length => string => {
        let intermediaryLength = 0
        return string.split(' ').reduce((finalString, current) => {
            intermediaryLength = (intermediaryLength + current.length > length) ?
                0 : intermediaryLength + current.length
            return finalString + (intermediaryLength ? ` ${current}` : ` ${current} \n`)
        }, "")
    }
    //example is a function
const exampleWithLengthSeven = makeAutoLinebreakerES8(7)
console.log("ES8 : \n" + exampleWithLengthSeven(string))
```

Comment: Happy to help. If you want always the same size and avoid passing the length, you can use the second function!

Answer (score 2):

You could take a limit for the line length and iterate a splitted string.

```js
var string = 'hello everyone. My name is PETER. hahahah ahahah ....',
    limit = 15,
    result = string.split(' ').reduce(function (r, s) {
        var line = r[r.length - 1] || '';
        line += (line && ' ') + s;
        if (r.length && line.length <= limit) {
            r[r.length - 1] = line;
        } else {
            r.push(s);
        }
        return r;
    }, []).join('\n');

console.log(result);
```